# Angular app not loading css font file - asp.net core app

Tags: css, webpack, asp.net-core, videogular

I'm an angular starter, and also just started test it in asp.net core (with Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates as blogged [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/)).

My problem is that one of my dependencies is not loading its css style,
I've edit `webpack.config.vendor.js` to include the `.css` in this section:

`...
entry: {
            vendor: [
...`

The package that I have problem with is [videogular](https://github.com/videogular/videogular2) which is a HTML5 video player for angular and its basic functionality works as expected, only some display features are lacking - in my specific case it's some icons on the player's component, which I thought that the vendor's config is responsible for include it. But unfortunately the Play button is not shown.
**Here's the component's ts file:**  (excerpt)

```
<vg-player (onPlayerReady)="onPlayerReady($event)">
    <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
    <vg-controls> 
        <vg-play-pause></vg-play-pause>
        <vg-playback-button></vg-playback-button>
        <vg-scrub-bar>       
            <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
            <vg-scrub-bar-cue-points [vgCuePoints]="metadataTrack.cues"></vg-scrub-bar-cue-points>
        </vg-scrub-bar>

        <vg-time-display vgProperty="left" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>
        <vg-time-display vgProperty="total" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>

        <vg-mute></vg-mute>

        <vg-fullscreen></vg-fullscreen>
    </vg-controls>
    <video [vgMedia]="media" #media id="singleVideo" preload="auto">
        <source [src]="selectedAssetVideoSource" type="video/mp4">      
    </video>
</vg-player>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, turns out that running `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js` sort this out, I had no idea that it's not part of the vs build process.